# Extending Liferay 6.1 session

Tags: liferay

I would like to extend Liferay 6.1 session, I thought about dialog showing up when session is about to expire or something like that. I know that Liferay has something similar, I can set f.e.

```
session.timeout.warning = 5
```

And when it would be 5 minutes to expire session there would be a message and a button to extend session for another 5 minutes.

Now, the question is : Is it possible to change the extending value (instead of 5 minutes I would like to extend it to 30 min) but still I want warning message to be shown 5 minutes before expiration ?

edit : Not sure it really matters, I'm using Liferay 6.1

**UPDATE**

In the end it turned out that Rushikesh was right all along. There is a bug in Liferay 6.1.1 which causes showing incorrect message about extending session by timeout.session.warning value instead of timeout.session. It was fixed in Liferay 6.1.3, see [here](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-33308)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly extend Liferay session, and also show session expiry warning, but not by just using `session.timeout.warning = 5` property.

Liferay's session timeout is 30 minutes by default, which is controlled through its web.xml file.

As [described here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Properties+6.0.5#section-Portal+Properties+6.0.5-Session), portal-ext.properties file has below settings for configuring session timeout warning. They are solely for the javascript that pops up the session timeout warning message on the top:

```
#
# Specify the number of minutes before a session expires. This value is
# always overridden by the value set in web.xml.
#
session.timeout=30

#
# Specify the number of minutes before a warning is sent to the user
# informing the user of the session expiration. Specify 0 to disable any
# warnings.
#
session.timeout.warning=5
```

When a user clicks on 'Extend' button on the warning message, Lifeary's session is extended by 'session-timout' value (e.g. 30 minutes in this case).

HTH!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm afraid it's not true, for sure not entirely. Session actually would be extended by 'session.timeout.warning'. It would be a countdown and the message : "Your session is about to expire in 5 mintues .Do you want to extend it by another 5 ?".

Comment: Firstly, it is up to you whether to believe it or not. I have pasted the properties along with Liferay's own documentation, which clearly says: "number of minutes before it should warn the user about session expiry". Secondly, it's the same for Liferay 6.1 as you can see here: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.2-ga3/portal-impl/src/portal.properties#L2554

Comment: Of course, I don't deny that 'session.timeout.warning' is a number of minutes befoure it should warn user about expiry. Also you are right that 'session.timeout' is a length of the session. I'm just saying that after clicking Extend button the session will be extended by the value of 'session.timeout.warning'. It's not matter of belief, I've spent couple of hours yesterday doing this

Comment: And the behaviour I'm expecting is the one you talking about, extending session by 'session.timeout', I'm just not sure how would I do that.

Comment: When you click on 'Extend' button, an AJAX call to the server is made (which does Nothing). Sensing some activity, the web container automatically extends session by the session timeout value declared in web.xml. Nothing fancy! Why would it refer to session.timeout value in Liferay's properties file?

Comment: I don't know why, it's just the way it is : I am working on it right now and the session is clearly extended by session.timeout.warning.

Comment: I own you an apology : YOU ARE RIGHT. After clicking on Extend button session is being extended to session.timeout. This all misunderstanding is due to the fact that Lifray 6.1 has a bug which causes showing incorrect message about extending session by session.timeout.warning value. I have always set timeout.session.warning almost as big as timeout.session so I didn't noticed that the message is incorrect in the first place. Sorry and thanks.